# Multi threading; pass object to another object

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to pass an object to another object. I know I have to pass `c` to `t1`. How do I do this

```
Thread t = new Thread(t1);
t.Start();

private static void t1(Class1 c)
{
    while (c.process_done == false)
    {
        Console.Write(".");
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, this object is being used outside the thread too? Then you have to lock it!

Comment: Follow up: if you got the answer you were looking, don't forget to mark it as correct. Regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok guys, everybody is missing the point the object is being used outside the thread as well. This way, it must be synchronized to avoid cross-thread exceptions.

So, the solution would be something like this:

```
//This is your MAIN thread
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(t1));
t.Start(new Class1());
//...
lock(c)
{
  c.magic_is_done = true;
}
//...

public static void t1(Class1 c)
{
  //this is your SECOND thread
  bool stop = false;
  do
  {
    Console.Write(".");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    lock(c)
    {
      stop = c.magic_is_done;
    }
    while(!stop)
  }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards

Comment: To me the question is more about the actual passing of the object to the new thread, but you make a much valid point. +1

Comment: A little bit of interpretation =) Notice that OP is using the object as a flag to stop the thread. +1 for your code, as well

Answer (score 4):

You could simply do:

```
Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(t1));
t.Start(new Class1());

public static void t1(object c)
{
  Class1 class1 = (Class1)c;
  ...
}
```

MSDN: [ParameterizedThreadStart Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.parameterizedthreadstart.aspx)

---

Or even better:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => t1(new Class1()));

public static void t1(Class1 c)
{
  // no need to cast the object here.
  ...
}
```

This approach permits multiple arguments and does not require you to cast the object to the desired class/struct.

Answer (score 2):

```
private static void DoSomething()
{
    Class1 whatYouWant = new Class1();
    Thread thread = new Thread(DoSomethingAsync);
    thread.Start(whatYouWant);
}

private static void DoSomethingAsync(object parameter)
{
    Class1 whatYouWant = parameter as Class1;
}
```